# How to get rid of undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined

When I `console.log` the array below, `undefined` is a part of each array item, I would like to know why is that and how to get rid of it?

```
new_colors.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var rgb_guesses = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < color_squares.length; i++) {
        var rgb_value = "rgb" + "(" + random() + "," + " " + random() + "," + " " + random() + ")";
        color_squares[i].style.background = rgb_value;
        rgb_guesses[i] += rgb_value;
    }
    guess_rgb.textContent = color_squares[3].style.background;
    console.log(rgb_guesses);
});
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `rgb_guesses[i] += rgb_value;` ... because += concatenates to a string, but your initial value is undefined, which, as a string is `undefined` - your code would work as expected if you change `+=` to just `=`

Comment: @JaromandaX how do I add the items to the array one by one without having undefined?

Comment: By using = each iteration you assign to a new element in the array. To be honest, push would be equivalent anyway

Answer (score 1):

You've created an empty array

So, the statement

```
rgb_guesses[i] += rgb_value;
```

is shorthand for

```
rgb_guesses[i] = rgb_guesses[i] + rgb_value;
```

Now as the array is empty, `rgb_guesses[i]` will be undefined until you assign a value to it ... undefined when coerced to a string, is "undefined"

So, your code is doing the equivalent of

```
rgb_guesses[i] = "undefined" + rgb_value;
```

Since you are only ever assigning a single value to each element in the array, you can change your code to simply

```
rgb_guesses[i] = rgb_value;
```

Or

```
rgb_guesses.push(rgb_value);
```